# How to implement this custom NN layer (implement the Accumulate function in the layer)?

Tags: neural-networks

[image: the Accumulate layer]

I will use this function layer to definte a custom LossFunction in the net.
How do I construct a NetGraph to implement this function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Documentation page for `Accumulate` provides us with a hint, namely that:

> Accumulate is equivalent to a particular case of FoldList:

```
In[1]:= FoldList[Plus, {a, b, c, d}] == Accumulate[{a, b, c, d}]
Out[1]= True
```

With this in mind, we turn to the new structural net operators, `NetFoldOperator`, and in-fact the very first example is this particular case!

```
core =NetGraph[{Plus}, {{NetPort["Input"], NetPort["State"]} -> 1}];
fold = NetFoldOperator[core];
fold[Range[10]]
Out[30]= {1., 3., 6., 10., 15., 21., 28., 36., 45., 55.}
```

Comment: It works, many thanks!